# P-values and distributions rejected

Tags: distributions, python, p-value

I am currently trying to see which distribution my data fits under.
My data frame is obtained from google trends and is a 99 by 2. It looks like this:

```
| Months   | iPhone4s       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2011-10  | 78             |
| 2011-11  | 74             |   
| 2011-12  | 65             |     
| 2012-01  | 70             |     
| 2012-02  | 61             |  
| ...      | ...            |
```

The dataset:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vdulpXpqk41xVav1T2CldBqFlL19MCY5tAunFeYUl-0/edit?usp=sharing

I am using the Kolmogorov-S Test. However, all my p-values should be rejected.
For instance, I get:

```
| Distribution   | P-val  (my value)    | expected p-val    |
| --------       | --------------       | --------------    | 
| Alpha          | 0.022490632432973987 | 0.002118806843987 |
| Beta           | 0.009994321204748092 | 2.29E+07          |
| Weibull        | 0.009994321889409574 | 0.0463990978659   |
| Normal         | 0.0064699884966764295| 0.000443423088507 |
```

(highest p-val was Alpha)

Although I have a loop to calculate all the distributions, this is a sample of my code for the normal test:

```
dist = getattr(stats, 'norm') #scipy 'normal' distribution object
parameters = dist.fit(df1.iPhone4s) # fit the data to the normal distr and get paramets
print(parameters) #(mean, std)
#Kolmogorov-S Test
stats.kstest(df1.iPhone4s, "norm", parameters)
```

I have tried so many things for the past 4 hours, and I am unable to understand my issue and why I am getting different p-values from the expected ones.
I am told that the data should fit under a Weibull distribution, with a pval of ~0.046. This is also less than alpha, so I am not sure what to do or what is going on.

Comment: Questions like this are a FAQ.  They all come down to understanding why you feel any need to fit a parametric distribution to your data in the first place.  What is your particular objective?

Comment: I am trying to replicate a paper that uses google trends data to predict product obsolescence. In order to model this evolution, I need to identify a distribution law that best approximates the data.

Comment: A better way to do that begins by considering what kinds and amounts of deviations from such a law would matter in your analysis and then assessing the consequences of those deviations.  Often, this results in a different choice than selecting a distribution from the (arbitrary) family supported by the software that happens to exhibit the greatest p-value.